How to replace template in c++
template<typename ActorType>
ActorType* CreateActor()
{
    EngineActor* NewActor = new ActorType();

    NewActor->SetParent(this); 
    NewActor->Start();
    return dynamic_cast<ActorType*>(NewActor);
}

This is a function that creates and returns a class received as a template.
I want to implement this without using a template. What should I do?
void* CreateActor(int _ActorSize,void* _Dummy)
{
    void* Result = malloc(_ActorSize);
    memcpy_s(Result, _ActorSize, _Dummy, _ActorSize);

    EngineActor* pCast = (EngineActor*)Result;
    pCast->SetParent(this); 
    pCast->Start();

    delete _Dummy;

    return result;
}

I tried a method where the caller creates a dummy, receives the size of the class and the dummy as parameters, and memcpys it.
But the problem is that the caller has to use the new operator to create a dummy.

Result->SetParent(this) on it's own is not valid C, nor is it in context valid C++. delete _Dummy is incredibly sus

Sorry I edited it

@nyori I think the point is "why is your question tagged with C?"

This smells like an XY problem.  Why are you trying to replace the template version?  If it's to use C, then this and delete are also issues with your current attempt.

I want to remove the template and change it to C style.

Why? The thing you are starting with is fairly idiomatic C++, which is doing something that really doesn't have an analog in C

Then you need to do much more work than merely remove the template. Language translations are often very hard. Often so hard that you're better off going back to the requirement and design documents and do a page one rewrite in the other language.

I want to separate the CreateActor function into a dll, but I want to remove the template from the interface.

CreateActor is not a function. CreateActor<SomeActorType> is a function.

Unrelated: dynamic_cast<ActorType*> of an instance of ActorType* is pointless. It's already of that type, if only it was declared as ActorType* NewActor = new ActorType();. Also, the function isn't following the single responsibility principle, as it creates an actor and starts it. And finally, it is leak-prone; it's better to return a unique_ptr<ActorType> instead.

There isn't a way of replacing CreateActor with one function.

This is a function that creates and returns a class received as a template.

No it isn't. A function template is not a function, it is a recipe for a family of functions.

I want to implement this without using a template. What should I do?

Copy and paste the definition for each different type you use it with.

Copy and paste the definition for each different type you use it with. Perhaps through a macro :)

That's kinda funny, @Victor . When I read the title the first thing to come to mind was #define template replacement. UB , of course, but everything really fun is UB.

So what did developers do in the days when there were no templates? They didn't define all the types.
I'm asking what method they used.

@nyori look up X Macros in C

@nyori yes, they did. There is no C equivalent to CreateActor. Your dll can't expose a function that creates an instance of a type that it doesn't know the structure of, but a template can.

I'm not a big fan of macros. If I had a complicated or long list of unavoidable duplication I wrote another program to parse a description file (which sometimes was the C source code that used the to-be generated code) and generate the necessary code. the generator would be built into the makefile to make sure it always regenerated if whatever it used a a descriptor was updated. In the old days it was a lot easier to debug a generated source file than try to step into macros. Debuggers are smarter now, so your mileage will vary.

@Victor: No need of MACRO, extern "C" /*DLL_EXPORT*/ ActorType1* CreateActor1() { return CreateActor<ActorType1>(); }.
